# Rake migrate Error - database doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, rake, datamapper, padrino, rails-postgresql

I have a padrino project that uses data mapper and postgres. When I run padrino rake dm:create it says that the database is created. However, when I run padrino rake dm:auto:migrate, I get the error - FATAL:  database "dbname_development" does not exist.

I'm working in a new environment but I tried a project I have that uses active record and had no problem.

I'm using postgres app on OSX and rbenv. Although, I did try rvm instead of rbenv since my other computer uses rvm (the project works fine on that computer) - same result. I also tried connecting to the created database with Induction and got the same error. If I go into psql though and get a list of databases, the database shows up.

I'm sort of stumped since ActiveRecord works and there are no issues when I run the project on another computer. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else who comes across something similar, I "fixed" it by doing sudo padrino rake dm:create. Still not sure why AR didn't need the root user.

Comment: Please update your question or your comment as answer and accept it. The "solution" smells quite a bit. In which directory were you working? Also, which versions were you using? Probably all that is not relevant anymore (question is more than a year old now).